# How does the positive-semidefinite Matrix for kernels looks like?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume we have a kernel k, we know by definition that $k(x,y) = x^TMy$, for a positive semi-definite Matrix M. However, how exactly does M look like? If we assume that x and y have two elements each, is M then equal to:

\begin{pmatrix} 
  k(x_1,y_1)     & k(x_1,y_2)\\ 
  k(x_2,y_1) & k(x_2,y_2)
\end{pmatrix}

?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a black box to produce $k(x,y)$ when it is given $x$ and $y$, without telling you $M$ explicitly.

We can recover $M$ as follows.

Let $e_i$ be the $i$-th standard unit vector, then $k(e_i,e_j)=e_i^TMe_j = M_{ij}$.

In particular for a $2 \times 2$ matrix, $$M= \begin{bmatrix} k(e_1,e_1) & k(e_1,e_2) \\ k(e_2, e_1) & k(e_2,e_2) \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Ah, but this would then also hold for arbitrary vectors, right?

Comment: you mean vector of arbitrary length? yes